# Dynamics 365 list lead statuscode enums by REST API

Tags: metadata, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to figure out how to list enum options for lead statuscode by REST API. I do request like:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='lead')/Attributes(LogicalName='statuscode')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet
```

but I get an error like:

```
"Navigation property Attributes With Id = LogicalName='statuscode' does not exist on Metadata Entity with ID = LogicalName='lead'"
```

What is the proper  endpoint to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StatusAttributeMetadata` instead of `PicklistAttributeMetadata`:

```html
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='lead')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StatusAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet($select=Options)
```

Comment: Thaks, this is exactly what I was looking for.